# Convert base-2 binary number string to int

Tags: python

I'd simply like to convert a base-2 binary number string into an int, something like this:

```
>>> '11111111'.fromBinaryToInt()
255
```

Is there a way to do this in Python?

Comment: While it doesn't really matter, a binary string typically means a string containing actual binary data (a byte contains two hexadecimal digits, ie "\x00" is a null byte).

Comment: Just to mention it: the other way around it goes like '{0:08b}'.format(65) (or f'{65:08b}').

Comment: it is uint rather than int. Please change the title

Answer (score 938, accepted):

You use the built-in `int()` function, and pass it the base of the input number, i.e. `2` for a binary number:

```
>>> int('11111111', 2)
255
```

Here is documentation for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), and for [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: In case someone is looking for the opposite: `bin(255)` -> `'0b11111111'`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/699892/638546) for additional details.

Comment: It should be noted that this only works for unsigned binary integers. For signed integers, the conversion options are a mess.

Comment: How to do this in python 3?

Comment: And note that in an interactive REPL session (as suggested by the `>>>` prompt), you don't need to use `print` at all. The OP's hypothetical example didn't. So it really should be identical in Python 2 and 3.

Comment: To add to @AkseliPalén comment: `bin (255)[2:]`

Answer (score 53):

Just type **0b11111111** in python interactive interface:

```
>>> 0b11111111
    255
```

Answer (score 38):

Another way to do this is by using the [`bitstring`](https://pypi.org/project/bitstring/) module:

```
>>> from bitstring import BitArray
>>> b = BitArray(bin='11111111')
>>> b.uint
255
```

Note that the unsigned integer (`uint`) is different from the signed integer (`int`):

```
>>> b.int
-1
```

Your question is really asking for the unsigned integer representation; this is an important distinction.

The `bitstring` module isn't a requirement, but it has lots of performant methods for turning input into and from bits into other forms, as well as manipulating them.

Answer (score 10):

Using int with base is the right way to go. I used to do this before I found int takes base also. It is basically a reduce applied on a list comprehension of the primitive way of converting binary to decimal ( e.g. 110 = 2**0 * 0 + 2 ** 1 * 1 + 2 ** 2 * 1)

```
add = lambda x,y : x + y
reduce(add, [int(x) * 2 ** y for x, y in zip(list(binstr), range(len(binstr) - 1, -1, -1))])
```

Comment: Instead of defining `add = lambda x, y: x + y`, `int.__add__` can be provided to reduce. E.g. `reduce(int.__add__, ...)`

Answer (score 5):

If you wanna know what is happening behind the scene, then here you go.

```
class Binary():
    def __init__(self, binNumber):
        self._binNumber = binNumber
        self._binNumber = self._binNumber[::-1]
        self._binNumber = list(self._binNumber)
        self._x = [1]
        self._count = 1
        self._change = 2
        self._amount = 0
        print(self._ToNumber(self._binNumber))
    def _ToNumber(self, number):
        self._number = number
        for i in range (1, len (self._number)):
            self._total = self._count * self._change
            self._count = self._total
            self._x.append(self._count)
        self._deep = zip(self._number, self._x)
        for self._k, self._v in self._deep:
            if self._k == '1':
                self._amount += self._v
        return self._amount

mo = Binary('101111110')
```

Answer (score 5):

For large matrix (10**5 rows and up) it is better to use a vectorized matmult. Pass in all rows and cols in one shot.  It is extremely fast. There is no looping in python here. I originally designed it for converting many binary columns like 0/1 for like 10 different genre columns in MovieLens into a single integer for each example row.

```
def BitsToIntAFast(bits):
  m,n = bits.shape
  a = 2**np.arange(n)[::-1]  # -1 reverses array of powers of 2 of same length as bits
  return bits @ a
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another concise way to do it not mentioned in any of the above answers:

```
>>> eval('0b' + '11111111')
255
```

Admittedly, it's probably not very fast, and it's a very very bad idea if the string is coming from something you don't have control over that could be malicious (such as user input), but for completeness' sake, it does work.

Comment: This might be fine for hard-coded constants, but there are multiple reasons why using `eval` is considered bad practice, especially when you would try to parse user input. See this post, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Comment: I love this answer, really creative

Answer (score 4):

A recursive Python implementation:

```
def int2bin(n):
    return int2bin(n >> 1) + [n & 1] if n > 1 else [1]
```

Answer (score 4):

> If you are using python3.6 or later you can use f-string to do the
>   conversion:

Binary to decimal:

```
>>> print(f'{0b1011010:#0}')
90

>>> bin_2_decimal = int(f'{0b1011010:#0}')
>>> bin_2_decimal
90
```

binary to octal hexa and etc.

```
>>> f'{0b1011010:#o}'
'0o132'  # octal

>>> f'{0b1011010:#x}'
'0x5a'   # hexadecimal

>>> f'{0b1011010:#0}'
'90'     # decimal
```

Pay attention to 2 piece of information separated by colon.

In this way, you can convert between {binary, octal, hexadecimal, decimal} to {binary, octal, hexadecimal, decimal} by changing right side of colon[:]

```
:#b -> converts to binary
:#o -> converts to octal
:#x -> converts to hexadecimal 
:#0 -> converts to decimal as above example
```

Try changing left side of colon to have octal/hexadecimal/decimal.

Answer (score 4):

For the record to go back and forth in basic python3:

```py
a = 10
bin(a)
# '0b1010'

int(bin(a), 2)
# 10
eval(bin(a))
# 10
```