# Python: Binary To Decimal Conversion

Tags: python, function, binary, decimal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert binary string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928240/convert-binary-string-to-int)

How would I convert this binary value '101011111' to decimal form in Python?

The function converts binary numbers into decimal numbers.

Inputs: string b: a binary number

Outputs: int d: a decimal representation of b

```
def Binary_to_Decimal(b):
    #what needs to be filled in
    return d
```

Answer (score 123):

You can use int casting which allows the base specification.

```
int(b, 2)  # Convert a binary string to a decimal int.
```