# Include a variable into the input function prompt

Tags: python

[image]
This is the question I was working on. I have created a function to convert binary number to decimal but what I couldn't figure out was how to get values while the number after Enter change
Enter 4 position value
Enter 3 position value
Enter 2 position value
Enter 1 position value

This is the code which I tried but apparently prompt inside input does not work like it does in print function. The numbers after Enter change depending on how much the user wants to enter.

```
a=int(input("Enter Number of digits : "))
while a<0:
    x=int(input("Enter ",a, " position value : "))
```

Comment: `print(x)` ? I don't understand exactly what is the problem.

Comment: what is your expected output? It's hard to understand what you're aking

Comment: I need the user to enter values do I cannot use the print command.

Comment: `while a<0:` - did you mean `while a>0:`? Based on your code, `a` will always be greater than `0`, so your `while` loop will never run

Comment: You also need to decrement `a`, otherwise your `while` loop will always run.

Comment: Yes I will change the while function. Thanks for pointing it out @Wondercricket

Comment: unlike `print`, `input` can't accept a tuple. Instead, form a real string: `input("enter " + str(a) + " position value : ")`. See https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/

Answer (score 2):

`input()` only expects a single argument; use string formatting to pass it a single string with your position value in it

One of these is likely what you're after (functionally identical, but you may have some preference)

```py
int(input(f"Enter {a} position value: "))
int(input("Enter {} position value: ".format(a)))
```

Multiple arguments to `input()` will raise `TypeError`!

```py
>>> input("foo", "bar")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Btw does the f after bracket helps it pass as a single string?

Comment: Anytime! The `f` is actually part of the string `f""` and makes it an "f-string" .. this enables you to use `{}` to format directly into the string https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals

Comment: Thanks this was new for me as I have only learnt the basics till now.

Comment: that's why we're all here! https://xkcd.com/1053/

Answer (score 0):

You could print before the input

```
b = 0

a = int(input("Enter Number of digits: "))
# digits = [0 for _ in range(a)]
b |= int(input("Enter MSB Value")) # or digits[a-1] = int(input())
a -= 1
while a > 0:
    print("Enter " , a, " position value : ")
    x = int(input())  # or digits[a] = int(input()) 
    b |= (x << a)  # just an example
    a -= 1
```

But if you want to put the input on the same line, then you need to format or concatenate the string to the input function, which is not what commas do

---

Regarding the storing of binary numbers, you should ideally be using bit-shift logic (as shown above) for that since you aren't actually entering decimal values, only individual bits. (Logic above not tested for your problem, btw)

And you don't need to write your own function to convert

[Python: Binary To Decimal Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656343/python-binary-to-decimal-conversion)

Comment: setting `end=""` in the print args could keep the `input()` on the same line! but just coercing the line to a single value and passing it as the single argument to `input()` is probably much better (even if this was with something wild like [`contextlib.redirect_stdout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout))

Comment: I would use int casting but here we have been specified to write a program so it is what it is. But thanks will remember this when I have to do this any other time.

Comment: @ViditAgarwal The problem you've asked about has nothing to do with "int casting". Plus, you're required to use "int casting" to get input to be numbers, anyway

Comment: Using print before input is also a great idea. Thanks for the tip.