# Python equivalent for Arduino's map function

Tags: python

Arduino has a [`map()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/) function that scales an integer value from one range to another. For example, you can take input from an 8-bit ADC sensor that ranges from 0–1024, and proportionally scale it to the range 0-100.

How would I do this in Python?

Comment: Do you mean doing a wraparound (101 would go back to 0, -10 would go to 90), or clamping (101 would go to 100, -10 would go to 0)?

Comment: My assumption would be scaling, which would be division (i.e. `math.floor(x / 10.24)` to scale `x` from the 0-1024 range to a roughly proportionate int in the 0-100 range).  In any case, yeah, "range" isn't a useful verb in this context and this question needs some clarification.

Comment: Providing a link to documentation of the C `range()` function you mention would probably also be helpful. I can't seem to Google up anything like what you describe, but I know very little about C. If you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70643627/edit) to sufficiently clarify it, it can be reopened.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant map() not range. Similar to this https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/arduino-map.html#Arduino_Map

Comment: Do mean [this map](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/)? Because there is clear math explanation of the implementation that can be used almost verbatim to implement your own function in python.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I 3dited my original question to clarify that. I was  looking at the range function in python and mixed them up.

Comment: Sound's like normalizing (re-scaling) between [a, b] for me despite the discretizing of signal values in ADC as @buran mentioned in map() function.

Answer (score 6):

Like [buran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4046632/buran) mentioned in the comments, the Arduino reference page for [`map()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/) shows the full implementation, which can be copied almost verbatim into Python.

Here's the Arduino C++ code:

```cpp
long map(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max) {
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

And here's what it would look like in Python. The only real gotcha is that `/` in Python returns a float even when both operands are integers; `//` is specifically integer division.

```
def map_range(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) // (in_max - in_min) + out_min
```

(I've also renamed it so it doesn't shadow Python's own [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), which is something different entirely.)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just divide by the original range max value and multiply by new range max-value?

```
new_value = (int) (my_value/max_value)*new_range_max
```

**EDIT:** if the original value is binary you can convert it to decimal by doing:

```
int(b, 2)  # Convert a binary string to a decimal int.
```

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/13656358/11381650

Comment: this applies only for ranges starting from 0 for in and out - as the example in the original question suggests. In this case the answer is correct. If speed counts and 0 start points are met this method is preferable. Hope this compensates the down grading a bit.

Comment: That is a good point -- ignoring different minima is more efficient in the event you know they'll all be zero, which may or may not be true for any given use case. However, this answer is syntactically invalid (it throws an error). And in the event one does need speed, true division is inefficient overkill if you want an integer in the end. Integer math is much faster than floating point.