# Python convert string to decimal

Tags: python, string, binary

I have a binary value that is stored in a variable. How do I convert it to decimal value or hex value??

```
 t = '0b'+bin(0o202)[::-1][:-2]
```

So the value of the t would be

```
 t = '0b01000001'
```

I need the value of the t converted to decimal or hex.

Comment: This was already answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928240/convert-binary-string-to-int

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hex()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) and [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
>>> hex(int(t, 2))  # hex
'0x41'
>>> 
>>> str(int(t, 2))  # decimal
'65'
```

Note that integers are by default represented in decimal, which is why the last line works as it should.