# Trying to convert binary numbers into base 10 manually. Running into an error. Python

Tags: python, binary, decimal

Here is a small snipet from the code which is causing the error.

```
num = input('Binary number? ')
base = input('base? ')

baseTen = 0
n = 1
for j in num:
    product = j*base**(len(num)-n)
    n += 1
    baseTen = baseTen + product
    print(baseTe)
```

The error message I recive is this:

```
    product = j*base**(len(num)-n)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

I am not sure what exactly is happening. Ive tried surrounding it with int() but that did not work. Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: `input()` returns a string.

Comment: Also see [Convert binary string to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928240/convert-binary-string-to-int)

Comment: I'm surprised you aren't getting an error on `for j in num:`

Comment: Try this:

    `num = input('Binary number? ')
    base = input('base? ')
    
    baseTen = 0
    n = 1
    for j in str(num):
        product = int(j)*base**(len(str(num))-n)
        n += 1
        baseTen = baseTen + product
        print(baseTen)` Also, I think you are a little confused b/c you are asking the user to enter a base. Since it is a conversion to binary, the input should always be 2.