# string (to binary) to int in python?

Tags: python

I want to make an int from a string in python. I thought to translate the string first to binary like this:

```
st = 'string'
binSt = ' '.join(format(ord(x), '08b') for x in st)
```

returns this:

```
01110011 01110100 01110010 01101001 01101110 01100111
```

And then I want to translate the binary( in groups of 8) to integers which should to return this:

```
115 116 114 105 110 103
```

How can I do this?
Is there maybe a special function in python or something?

Comment: This is probably what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8928256/5712767

Comment: indeed, sorry, I've edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the solution for binary to int here: [Convert base-2 binary number string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928240/convert-binary-string-to-int)

```
 binSt = ' '.join([str(int(format(ord(x), '08b'), 2)) for x in st])
```

And if you just want an array of ints

```
 int_array = [int(format(ord(x), '08b'), 2) for x in st]
```

Addressing SpoonMeiser comments. you can avoid intermediate conversions with ord(x)

```
 int_array = [ord(x) for x in st]
```

Comment: Having the int -> binary and binary -> int on one line like this seems pointless. If you didn't want the intermediate value (the binary representation) you'd just use `ord(x)`

Comment: I was answering the OPs question to translate the binary strings to ints. I agree the extra conversions can be avoided.

Comment: I just mean that it probably a less helpful answer written this way. I think it's implied that the OP actually wanted the binary representation for some reason

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [int()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) function:

```
result = ''
st = 'string'
binSt = ' '.join(format(ord(x), '08b') for x in st)
binSt_split = binSt.split()
for split in binSt_split:
    result = result + str(int(split,2) + ' '
print result
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do

```
r = [int(numbs, 2) for numbs in binSt.split(' ')]
```

`int(str, baseNumber)` will read the string `str` and convert it to `int` using `baseNumber`

so `int("0xFF", 16) = 255` and `int("11", 2) = 3`

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray)?

```
>>> barr = bytearray('string')
>>> barr[0]
115
```

Bytearray does exactly what you want -- It interprets each character in the string as an integer in the range from `0` -> `255`.

Answer (score 1):

String to binary and then to decimal :

```
st = 'string'
binSt = ' '.join(format(ord(x), '08b') for x in st)
binSt
##'01110011 01110100 01110010 01101001 01101110 01100111'
bin=binSt.split()
bin
##['01110011', '01110100', '01110010', '01101001', '01101110', '01100111']
print(map(lambda x: int(x,2), bin))
##[115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]
```

`##` is used for outputs