# Return non- string number from the output of hex to binary conversion?

Tags: python, binary, bit-manipulation

How can i get return value after converting hex value to binary string?

I'm always getting string binary which is not useful for bit operation.

i.e
`bin(int(str('0x460001'), 16))` is always `0b10001100000000000000001`, instead I want `0b10001100000000000000001` as my output.

For that binary value I want to perform an operation which requires non string value, like:

```
0b10001100000000000000001 | 0b10001100100000000000001
```

Please let me know if there is any option or library I can use for it.

Comment: Just use an `int`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8928256/58129

Comment: You can specify a base when sending an input to the `int` constructor.  So `int('0x460001', 16) == 4587521`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert base-2 binary number string to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928240/convert-base-2-binary-number-string-to-int)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No, int will convert it into decimal number which I don't want. I just want whole binary, just type should be int.

Comment: An int can be *displayed* as binary, hex, decimal, but it is still an int.

Comment: @VatsalSoni you don't "convert to a decimal number", the underlying machine representation of an `int` is a binary representation. You are getting hung up with how things are being printed to the screen. Stop at `int`.

Comment: 0x460001 *is* an `int`.  To do binary operation, do not convert to a string.  Claudio's answer is a long form of this advice.

Answer (score 1):

Probably to your surprise the problem you see isn't a problem at all because:

```
print( type(0b10001100100011000000001) )

# gives: <class 'int'> (or int in Python 2)
```

`0b10001100100011000000001` IS a NUMBER, not a string ...
so you can do binary operations directly with it.

Just try this:

```
print( 0x460001 == 0b10001100000000000000001 ) # gives True
print( 0x460001 == 4587521 )                   # gives also True
print( 4587521  == 0b10001100000000000000001 ) # gives True
```

or this:

```
print( type(0x460001), type(0b10001100000000000000001), type(4587521) )
# gives <class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
```

It doesn't matter HOW you write a number it will be the same number, but

```
print( "0x460001" == 0b10001100000000000000001 ) # gives False
```

will give you `False` as `"0x460001"` is a string not a number.

Anyway, until you understand the above, you can play around with following code snippets:

```
def bitwiseORforBinaryNumbers(bin1, bin2):
  return bin( bin1 | bin2 )

print( bitwiseORforBinaryNumbers(
   0b10001100000011000000001, 
   0b10001100100000000000001) )
#  0b10001100100011000000001
```

or just written directly:

```
print( 
  bin( 0b10001100000011000000001 | 
       0b10001100100000000000001 ) ) 
#      0b10001100100011000000001
```

The same for strings with binary representations of a number look like:

```
def bitwiseORforStringsWithBinaryValue(binStr1, binStr2):
  return bin(int(binStr1,2) | int(binStr2,2))

print( bitwiseORforStringsWithBinaryValue("0b10001100000011000000001", "0b10001100100000000000001") )
# gives:
0b10001100100011000000001
```

or just done directly in code:

```
print( bin( int("0b10001100000011000000001",2) | int("0b10001100100000000000001",2) ) )
```