# using the len() function

Tags: python

i keep getting the error object type int has no len() not sure why. I just learned about the len function so an explanation of why its doing this would be great thanks

```
bits=int(input("enter an 8-bit binary number"))

for i in range (0,8):
    if len(bits) >8 or len(bits) <8:
        print("must enter an 8 bit number")
```

Comment: These are two separate problems. The first one is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response), the second one is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928240/convert-base-2-binary-number-string-to-int).

Comment: `if bits >8 and bits <8:` will never be true because it's impossible for `bits` to be both > 8 **`and`** be < 8 (or any other value for that matter) at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

that should be easy, because python's "int" accepts "base" param which tells it
which numeric base to use

```
strbin = input('enter bin value\n')
converted = int(strbin,base=2)
print('base 2 converted to base 10 is: ', converted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because you read a string with `input` but *immediately* convert it to an int:

```
bits=int(input("enter an 8-bit binary number"))
     --- there!
```

An input such as `"00110011"` gets stored into `bits` as the decimal value `110011`, without the leading zeroes. And as the error says, an `int` has no `len`.

Remove the cast to `int` to make that part work. But there are *lots* of additional errors in your (original) code – I hope I got them all. (Pardon the exclamation marks, but all of your mistakes warranted at least one.)

Your original code was

```
bits=int(input("enter an 8-bit binary number"))

for i in range (0,8):
    if bits >8 and bits <8:
        print("must enter an 8 bit number")

    if input >1:
        print("must enter a 1 or 0")
    else:
           rem=bits%10
           sum=((2**i)*rem)
           bits = int(bits/10)
           print(sum)
```

adjusted to

```python
bits=input("enter an 8-bit binary number")

sum = 0 # initialize variables first!

if len(bits) != 8:  # test before the loop!
    print("must enter an 8 bit number")
else:
    for i in range (8): # default start is already '0'!
        # if i > 1: # not 'input'! also, i is not the input!
        if bits[i] < '0' or bits[i] > '1':  # better also test for '0'
            print("must enter a 1 or 0")
        # else: only add when the input value is '1'
        elif bits[i] == '1':
            # rem = bits%10         # you are not dealing with a decimal value!
            # sum = ((2**i)*rem)    # ADD the previous value!
            sum += 2**i
            # bits = int(bits/10)   # again, this is for a decimal input

    # mind your indentation, this does NOT go inside the loop
    print(sum)
```