# Binary integer number to string showing getting the same number python

Tags: python, string, binary, integer

Bad conversion binary integer number to string

I have tried parsing to char, binary and then to string, but it doesn't work in the proper way as I want to.

```
def xorGate(self):
    xorNumber= ''
    #receiving the 2 integers
    numBin1 = self.__sanearInput(self.inputParams[0])
    numBin2 = self.__sanearInput(self.inputParams[1])
    #act
    xorNumber=numBin1^numBin2
    #result
    xorNumber=str(xorNumber)
    self.outputParams.append(xorNumber)
```

I'm putting as a parameters "1000" & "1010". Finally, it parses the result to string getting "26" instead of "0010".

Comment: Your "binary" inputs are actually in decimal. `1000 ^ 1010` with base 10 is 26.

Comment: To get actual binary values from those characters, use `'0b1000'` and `'0b1010'` or `int('1000', 2)` and `int('1010', 2)` or something like them. The best way depends on how you get those values into `inputParams`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the class-method stuff that is irrelevant to the question, if I do this:

```
>>> numbin1 = 0b1000
>>> numbin2 = 0b1010
>>> xornumber = numbin1 ^ numbin2
```

I get

```
>>> xornumber
2
>>> bin(xornumber)
'0b10'
```

which is the right answer. What is happening is you are using the constants `1000` and `1010`, which are *decimal* constants, and expecting Python to interpret them as binary just because you are using the `^` operator. Like this:

```
>>> bin(1000)
'0b1111101000'
>>> bin(1010)
'0b1111110010'
>>> bin(1000 ^ 1010)
'0b11010'
```

and `0b11010` *is* `26`.

To interpret a user's input string of 1s and 0s as an integer represented in binary, consult [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928240/convert-base-2-binary-number-string-to-int).

Comment: What I want as a result is a string like "0b11010",  not the actual number

Comment: And my answer shows you how to do that. Call `bin()`.