# how can I doing the conversion between decimal and binary values?

Tags: python, binary, decimal, encode, data-conversion

I'm novice in python and I develop this function to retrieve coilstatus but in binary format:

```
 def reg_val_list1(s):
v = []
for p in s:
    if p.haslayer('ModbusADUResponse'):
        try:
            if p['ModbusADUResponse'][1].funcCode == 1:
                v += p['ModbusADUResponse'][1].coilStatus
        except AttributeError:
            pass

return v
```

I want to obtain a binary values instead of a decimals ones. Here is my function

This function returns me values ​​in decimal like 64,3, ... and I would like to have these same values ​​in binary ie:

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0: 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0 = 64 and 1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0 = 3

I modified the function by putting several solutions but none of them work. I made this change:

```
def reg_val_list1(s):
v = []
u = []
for p in s:
    if p.haslayer('ModbusADUResponse'):
        try:
            if p['ModbusADUResponse'][1].funcCode == 1:
                v += p['ModbusADUResponse'][1].coilStatus
                u = "{0:b}".format(v)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
   return u
```

I also tried this:

```
def reg_val_list1(s):
v = []
for p in s:
    if p.haslayer('ModbusADUResponse'):
        try:
            if p['ModbusADUResponse'][1].funcCode == 1:
                v += bin (p['ModbusADUResponse'][1].coilStatus)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
   return v
```

and encode() too

But nothing works. any help please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert base-2 binary number string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928240/convert-base-2-binary-number-string-to-int)

Comment: I think the question is exactly opposite - from decimal to binary, not binary to int. However, the example `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0: 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0 = 64` doesn't make sense - binary representation of 64 is 1000000.

Comment: Yeah you're right from decimal to binary. I give the bits as I retrieve them from the pcap file but you're right :  0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0 = 64 and 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1 = 3. in the proposed forum, people propose function bin() but it doesn't work