# a basic eight number string to eight bit binary number

Tags: python, binary

eight character (zero and one) string -> turn it into 8 bit binary number -> perform binary operation -> turn back into 8 0/1 string

```
>>> the_entry = "00000000"
>>> the_binary number = 8CharacterStringIntoThe8CharacterBinaryNumber(the_entry)
>>> the_binary_number << 1 # any binary operation
>>> the_result_string = EightCharacterBinaryNumberIntoEightCharacterString(the_binary_number)
```

this is soo simple, I refuse to write my own method, but obviously, in th 180000 possible results, I cannot find the one related to my question.

Do you hold the magic??

Comment: I didn't understand what your question is. Can you please phrase this more clearly?

Comment: I would like to turn an eight number string into an 8 bit binary number, perform bitwise operations on the binary and return the 8character string representation of this number

Comment: Are you asking this? (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928240/convert-base-2-binary-number-string-to-int; (2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary-string

Comment: "I refuse to write my own method" That's not how to win a crowd...

Comment: I am reluctant of reinventing the wheel, maybe that would sound better]

Comment: Indeed that would help. As would clearly defining what you need, seeing how you seem not satisfied with the answer/dupes you got. Even though they do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you are not getting the point, that is all right, you seem not to be too used with communities, that is also allright, thank you for your time anyway, even though unsupportive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are simple basic operations:

```
entry = "00000000"
number = int(entry, 2)
result = f"{number:08b}"
```

Comment: but then your number will be an integer, not a binary or byte ...

Comment: This was it!! thank you so much!! simple and concise