# TLV (Type Length Value) Packet

Tags: python-3.x

i'm trying to create a module to pack and unpack data like:
pack: encode them to binary string
unpack: decode them from binary string to integr
: ord(decodet_binary_string)
but i have long time trying to continue my code and the same error was shown to me
the cause of encoding to binary is:
some data can't be converted to utf-8 or utf-16 or utf-32 so when we turn them to binary string and encode the we can use utf-8 to encode them :)

```
    class tlv_packet:
        def __init__(self, bitseq = True):
                self.tlv_packet = True
                self.bitseq = bitseq

        def encode(self, data):
                self.data = ""
                if data.isascii() == True:
                        self.type = 0
                else:
                        self.type = 256
                for char in range(0, len(data)):
                        self.data += ""
                self.binary_type = bin(self.type)
                self.binary_string = "".join(f"{bin(ord(i))}" for i in data) #:08b}" for i in s)
                self.binary_length = len(self.binary_string)
                return self.binary_type, self.binary_length, self.binary_string

        def decode(self, data = ""):
                self.data_vector = data.split('b')
                self.data = ""
                for count in range(0, len(self.data_vector)):
                        char = self.data_vector[count]
                        order = 0b0
                        for char_order in range(0, len(self.data_vector[count])):
                                if self.data_vector[count][char_order] == '1':
                                        order += 1
                                elif self.data_vector[count][char_order] == '0':
                                        order += 0
                        print(self.data_vector[count])
                        self.data += chr(order)
                self.data_length = len(self.data)
                return self.data_length, self.data
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the decode function is:

```
        def decode(self, data = ""):
            self.data_vector = data.split('0b')
            self.data_vector.remove('')
            self.data_string = ""
            for i in range(0, len(self.data_vector)):
                    self.char_order = int(self.data_vector[i], 2)
                    self.data_string += chr(self.char_order)
            self.data_length = len(self.data)
            return self.data_length, self.data_string
```

Find it in:[convert bin string to int value in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928240/convert-base-2-binary-number-string-to-int)