# Turning a binary in string form to an integer

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, binary

I have a file that contains this binary strings:

```
00100
11110
10110
10111
```

How do I convert all the lines to integers?

The out put I would want for example is:

```
4
30
23
22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int('00100', 2)
int('11110', 2)
int('10110', 2)
int('10111', 2)
```

See Also : [Convert base-2 binary number string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928240/convert-base-2-binary-number-string-to-int)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's consider best not to answer questions that are known to be duplicates. Doing so can attract downvotes. See [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/478746) from the Meta FAQ for further details and rational.