# How to remove beginning of a string

Tags: python, binary, decimal, converters

So at school, we are meant to be making a binary and decimal converter.
So far I have discovered the `bin()` function and it gives me roughly what I need:

```
bin(10)
#0b1010
```

However, I was wandering how I would go about removing the `0b` at the beginning so that I am left with simply `1010`.

Does anyone actually know what the `0b` means?

Comment: the 0b means its binary, just like 0x means its hex.

Answer (score 4):

The `0b` means it is binary.  And, to remove it, simply do this:

```
>>> bin(10)
'0b1010'
>>> bin(10)[2:]
'1010'
>>> bin(12345)
'0b11000000111001'
>>> bin(12345)[2:]
'11000000111001'
>>>
```

This solution takes advantage of Python's [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking, but I think its "How do i trim the start of a string off"

And you can do that with slicing:

```
>>> s = "I am a string"
>>> s[5:]
'a string'
```

So in your case it would be:

```
>>> bin(10)[2:]
'1010'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to convert a number to binary without the `0b` at the beginning

```
>>> '{0:0b}'.format(10)
'1010'
```

This question will be helpful to you  [Converting integer to binary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411085/converting-integer-to-binary-in-python)