# using python to convert integer to 8bit binarey

Tags: python, binary

Im working on a program which converts binary into integers (easy enough) however I then need to convert the integers back into 8bit binary representation. I have had a look, and I can do it mathematically, but I was wondering if there was a handy python function that did this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting integer to binary in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411085/converting-integer-to-binary-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get precisely 8 bits, use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatstrings):

A demo:

```
>>> '{0:08b}'.format(22)
'00010110'
```

Comment: Hi, this puts 0b at the beginning of the string, and it isn't in 8bit.  is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Perfect, thanks... will accept in 7 mins when the software lets me! lol

Comment: @ChrisHeadleand Good, glad to have been of assistance. Upvotes are also greatly appreciated if you haven't already. :)