# How to generate decimal in range for 24 bit?

Tags: php, python, math

I have 24 bit of binary, which is
111010001100001010011000
equals to 15254168

I only "guess" its 24 bit, because binary length is 24.

I would like to generate all 24 bit decimals programmaticly. (C, PHP or Python)

2**24 returns 16.777.216

So there are 16.777.216 other decimals (combinations). How can i generate them?

I can't understand the "range" of 24 bit.
May someone help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: in which programming language?

Comment: btw, the answer is trivial: all numbers from 0 to 2^24 - 1

Comment: @mescalinum i prefer PHP and Python

Comment: can you explain why do you need an "algorithm" for this task?

Comment: @mescalinum i am experimenting with Radiofrequency (RF) and its only accepts decimal values. Software does the binary conversion. So i have to provide 24 bit decimals.

Comment: so, is this a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411085/converting-integer-to-binary-in-python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!-- language: python -->
```

Is this what you want?

```
>>> n = 3
>>> result = [bin(k)[2:].rjust(n, '0') for k in xrange(2**n)]
>>> print result
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
>>> n = 24
```

Comment: `['{:024b}'.format(k) for k in range(2**24)]` is faster

Answer (score 2):

24bits just mean there are 24 bits(zeros or ones) that together create a binary number.

If you want all combinations, or all numbers that can be expressed with 24 bits, it is just range from 0 to 16777215. Why? here is the table in format (binary = decimal):

```
000000000000000000000000 = 0
000000000000000000000001 = 1
000000000000000000000010 = 2
000000000000000000000011 = 3
....
....
111111111111111111111110 = 16777214
111111111111111111111111 = 16777215
```

you dont really need to generate anything. You can check the binary to decimal here: http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-decimal-converter

Another thing: Sometimes in binary, the leading zeros are omitted. So decimal three is not 000000000000000000000011 but rather just 11. If the length is 24 and first digit is 1, its still just range 8388608 - 16777215

Comment: Thank you. However i have to "generate" for a software. First digit is 0, so the whole range 1-16777215, right? I just need to "padding" with zeroes to make it 24 bit binary. Right?

Comment: If you need a list of all 16 millions binary numbers you do this in python:

Comment: for dec in range(0,2**24):
 print("{:0>24}".format(bin(dec)[2:]))