# Converting integer array to binary array in python

Tags: python, arrays, binary

I am trying to convert an array with integers to binary, using python 2.7.

A simplified version of my code is the following:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import numpy as np

 a=np.array([6,1,5,0,2])
 b=np.array(np.zeros((5)))

for i in range(10):
    b[i]=bin(int(a[i])).zfill(8)
```

The code gives me the error message:

```
b[i]=bin(int(a[i])).zfill(8)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0000b110
```

What is wrong with my code?
Is there another way to do this?
The original code is part of a much greater project with 2 dimensional arrays.

p.s I'm a relative novice to Python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting integer to binary in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411085/converting-integer-to-binary-in-python)

Comment: The ValueError comes from the fact that you created an accidental monstrosity. bin(6)  is `'0b110'` and you needed to get rid of the `0b` part before padding with 0s. The error message literally points out that there is something wrong with `0000b110`. Also, why are your array of size 5 but you do `for i in range(10):`?

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response!

Comment: The size of the array (10) was set accidentally. In the original code it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numpy attempts to convert your binary number to a `float`, except that your number contains a `b` which can't be interpreted; this character was added by the `bin` function, eg. `bin(2)` is `0b10`. You should remove this `b` character before your `zfill` like this by using a "slice" to remove the first 2 characters:

```
b[i]=bin(int(a[i]))[2:].zfill(8)
```

Answer (score 1):

`bin` will create a string that starts with `0b` indicating that it is a binary representation. If you only want the binary representation you have to slice the first two characters before you call `zfill`.

Instead of doing this, you could use `format` like so

```
b[i] = '{:08b}'.format(a[i])
```

Basically, this will print the binary representation of `a[i]` padded with `0` until it has length 8.

See the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for further details.