# Python - Binary to decimal

Tags: python, variables, binary, integer

I don't know much about Python, so sorry if this sounds silly. I am getting a string of 0s and 1s from an Arduino, and I need to convert it to a 'regular' number. I've found out how to convert a binary string to a decimal integer pretty easily, but how would I convert it if my binary string is stored in a variable ?

Let's say I've got a=00000110

int(a, 2) doesn't work (tells me "int() can't convert non-string with explicit base")

Is there a specific syntax that I should be aware of ? Can't I put a variable in here ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try this with the appropriate input: **a = "00000110"**.  What you showed is trying to covert the integer 110, not a string.

Comment: First result from Google: [Converting integer to binary in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411085/converting-integer-to-binary-in-python)

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing ! It's working now. Thanks !

Comment: If  you think you have `00000110` and it is not a string you have 72.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham So Python 2 is interpreting it as octal?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga,  if they actually had  `a=00000110`  then it would be 
  octal in python2, in python3 it would be a SyntaxError. In this case they seemed to have  called `int(a)` where a is actually a str and teh tried to convert that.