# Matplotlib display axis as binary

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, graphics

I'm attempting to label the x-axis of my graph in binary instead of float values in Python 2.7. I'm attempting to use `FormatStrFormatter('%b')` which according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions) provided by the Python Software Foundation should work. I'd also like all the binary strings to be the same length of characters. I've also consulted this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411085/converting-integer-to-binary-in-python).

The error I'm getting is:

> ValueError: unsupported format character 'b' (0x62) at index 1

I've tried to do it like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%b'))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 110, 10))

x = np.arange(1, 10, 0.1)
plt.plot(x, x**2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `'%b' % 12` throws an error in python 3.6 for me whereas `'%x'` and `'%o'` don't. Are you sure it's part of the % format spec?

Comment: Yes. Hexadecimal (x) works fine.

Comment: ? That didn't answer my question -- MatPlotLib doesn't support the binary `%b` spec because the `str.__mod__` function doesn't. Look at the last 2 lines of your error: `return self.fmt % x
ValueError: unsupported format character 'b' (0x62) at index 1`

Comment: It should have as b for binary is above those two definitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a `StrMethodFormatter`, this works well also with the `b` option.

```
StrMethodFormatter("{x:b}")
```

However leading zeros require to know how many of them you expect (here 7).

```
StrMethodFormatter("{x:07b}")
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter("{x:07b}"))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 110, 10))

x = np.arange(1, 10, 0.1)
plt.plot(x, x**2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
…
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter("{:b}".format))
```

It should work in Python 3.5.