# How to convert decimal to binary value of rows in multindex dataframe (python)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binary, multi-index

Could you let me know how to onvert decimal to binary value of rows in multindex dataframe?

below is dataframe I used

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

raw_data = {'Function': ['env', 'env', 'env', 'func1', 'func1', 'func1'],
            'Type': ['In', 'In', 'In', 'In','In', 'out'],
            'Name': ['Volt', 'Temp', 'BD#', 'Name1','Name2', 'Name3'],
            'Val1': ['Max', 'High', '1', '3', '5', '6'],
            'Val2': ['Typ', 'Mid', '2', '4', '7', '6'],
            'Val3': ['Min', 'Low', '3', '3', '6', '3'],
            'Val4': ['Max', 'High', '4', '3', '9', '4'],
            'Val5': ['Max', 'Low', '5', '3', '4', '5'] }
df = DataFrame(raw_data)
df= df.set_index(["Function", "Type","Name"])
print (df)
```

below is printed dataframe

```
                            Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4    Val5
 Function   Type    Name                    
 env        In      Volt    Max     Typ     Min     Max     Max
                    Temp    High    Mid     Low     High    Low
                    BD#     1       2       3       4       5
 func1      In      Name1   3       4       3       3       3
                    Name2   5       7       6       9       4
            out     Name3   6       6       3       4       5
```

I want to convert decimal to binary values of rows(func1 - In - Name1, Name2) in multi-index dataframe.

below is expected df I want.

```
                            Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4    Val5
 Function   Type    Name                    
 env        In      Volt    Max     Typ     Min     Max     Max
                    Temp    High    Mid     Low     High    Low
                    BD#     1       2       3       4       5
 func1      In      Name1   11      100     11      11      11
                    Name2   101     111     110     1001    100
            out     Name3   6       6       3       4       5
```

I have tried to get right results but I failed. TT

Plz let me know how to resolve it simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) for create conditions, chain together and set new values by [`f-string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411085/converting-integer-to-binary-in-python)s:

```
m1 = df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'func1'
m2 = df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'In'

df[m1 & m2] = df[m1 & m2].astype(int).applymap(lambda x: f'{x:b}')
print (df)
                     Val1 Val2 Val3  Val4 Val5
Function Type Name                            
env      In   Volt    Max  Typ  Min   Max  Max
              Temp   High  Mid  Low  High  Low
              BD#       1    2    3     4    5
func1    In   Name1    11  100   11    11   11
              Name2   101  111  110  1001  100
         out  Name3     6    6    3     4    5
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your answer. I felt that it is hard to change values in row of dataframe. I didn't even think of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

By creating mask of the dataframe:

```
mask = ((df.index.get_level_values('Function') == 'func1')&
                (df.index.get_level_values('Type') == 'In')&
                (df.index.get_level_values('Name').isin(['Name1', 'Name2'])))

df[mask] = df[mask].astype(int).applymap(lambda x: format(x, 'b'))  

print(df[mask])

                     Val1 Val2 Val3  Val4 Val5
Function Type Name                            
env      In   Volt    Max  Typ  Min   Max  Max
              Temp   High  Mid  Low  High  Low
              BD#       1    2    3     4    5
func1    In   Name1    11  100   11    11   11
              Name2   101  111  110  1001  100
         out  Name3     6    6    3     4    5
```

Comment: I learned using mask of dataframe and applymap thanks to your answer. I appreciate it!!