# How can I convert a numpy to a binary (size 8 bits)

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I am searching for a dynamic way to perform a numpy convert (integer to binary).
I tried to use the 'astype' way but it didn't work out.

I got a 3-dim matrix like that one:

```
x = np.array([[[1, 2, 44],[1,5,3]],[[7, 88, 12],[1,15,60]]])
```

I would like to convert each value of x to its binary form (max size of 8 bits)
for example, if x includes 6 it will be converted to '00000110'.

This is a reference for how to convert integer to binary as I need:
[Converting integer to binary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411085/converting-integer-to-binary-in-python)

Comment: What you need is not a type conversion (and that is why `astype` didn't work), but a string representation of the numbers in your array (decimal form into binary form)

Comment: `bin` (or any equivalent) has to applied to each array element.  There isn't compiled method that does that for the whole array at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(lambda i: '{0:08b}'.format(i))
x_bin = vfunc(x)
```

Output of `print(x_bin)`:

```
[[['00000001' '00000010' '00101100']
  ['00000001' '00000101' '00000011']]

 [['00000111' '01011000' '00001100']
  ['00000001' '00001111' '00111100']]]
```

Comment: @user5650029 Does this answer your question?