# Array values in binary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written a script that gets n bit values and put them together in a list. I need to make the result in binary. It gives me errors in every single method/function I try. I'm fairly new to Python, I would appreciate some help.

```
from itertools import product
arr = 0
val_x = []
val_y =[]
n = int(input('n = '))

if __name__ == "__main__":

for x in range (0, n + 1):
    for y in range (0, n + 1):
        if y == 0:
            arr += 1
    if arr == 1:
        val_x.append(x)
        val_y.append(x)
    arr = 0

res = list(product(val_x, val_y))
print(res)
```

The result I get is:

```
n = 2
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

I need it in binary like this:

```
[(00, 00), (00, 01), (00, 10), (01, 00), (01, 01), (01, 10), (10, 00), (10, 01), (10, 10)]
```

Comment: Here is the post which you can refer, https://stackoverflow.com/q/10411085/4985099

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using bin ->

```
from itertools import product
arr = 0
val_x = []
val_y =[]
n = int(input('n = '))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for x in range(n + 1):
        for y in range(n + 1):
            if y == 0:
                arr += 1
        if arr == 1:
            val_x.append(bin(x)[2:]) #by bin you can convert the int to binary
            val_y.append(bin(x)[2:])
        arr = 0

res = list(product(val_x, val_y))
print(res)
```

Using f-strings(as suggested by ash)- Here, the idea is instead of appending integers append their binary format.

```
from itertools import product
arr = 0
val_x = []
val_y =[]
n = int(input('n = '))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    for x in range(n + 1):
        for y in range(n + 1):
            if y == 0:
                arr += 1
        if arr == 1:

            val_x.append(f"{x:02b}")
            val_y.append(f"{x:02b}")
        arr = 0

res = list(product(val_x, val_y))
print(res)
```

Comment: There isn't any explanation on here - I would add some for the benefit of our poster if you get time :)

Answer (score 1):

the good news is that your binary is being stored correctly, you can do whatever you like to it - when you want to represent it as binary you can use string formatting with `b` get a binary string out.

```
>>> a = 5
>>> f"{a:b}"
'101'
```

If you want it to be a certain length (always 2 in your case) you can do this:

```
>>> a = 0
>>> f"{a:02b}"
'00'
```