# How can I print in an f-string an IP address in the dotted binary notation from the output of inet_pton()?

Tags: python, numbers, ip-address, string-interpolation

The following code [is supposed to take an IP from its user, convert it to the binary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.inet_pton) and print it to the screen.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from socket import inet_aton, inet_pton, AF_INET

ip = input("IP?\n")

ip = inet_pton(AF_INET, ip) 

print(f"{ip}")
```

When given `185.254.27.69` it prints
`b'\xb9\xfe\x1bE'` .`f"{ip:08b}"` [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10411108/11422610), perhaps because of the three dots in between the fours octets.. How could I get the dotted binary format of an IP printed on the screen? Any resources of use?

Comment: *binary* form? What does that mean?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I mean the dotted binary notation. I've just modified the question in response to your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, I don't see a reason to use inet_pton here. It converts to packed bytes, when you want a binary representation of the numbers (I assume):

```py
ip = input("IP?\n")
print('.'.join(f'{int(num):08b}' for num in ip.split('.')))
```

For the input you supplied:

```
IP?
185.254.27.69
10111001.11111110.00011011.01000101
```

Answer (score 1):

this code works for binary ip and keeps leading zeros:

```
from socket import inet_aton, inet_pton, AF_INET

ip = ip2 = input("IP?\n")

ip = inet_pton(AF_INET, ip)
ip2 = ip2.split(".")
ip3 = ""
for ip in ip2:
    ip = int(ip)
    if len(ip3) == 0:
        zeros = str(bin(ip)[2:]).zfill(8)
        ip3 += zeros
    else:
        zeros = str(bin(ip)[2:]).zfill(8)
        ip3 += "." + zeros
print(f"{ip3}")
```

Comment: It prints the IP in the original format - the same as given. Whereas when I give an address as `185.254.27.69`  I want to receive something like `10111001.11111110.11011.1000101`

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your request, Answer Updated

Comment: The problem with your code is that it does not print leading zeros, e.g. it outputs `10111001.11111110.11011.1000101` instead of `10111001.11111110.00011011.1000101`

Comment: it is exactly as you requested, plz check your first comment