# How would I turn a number into its binary representation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I turn a number into denary from binary and whats wrong with the code:

```
print (" Enter a number")
realnum = int(input())
print("In Binary that is", bin(realnum)[2:])
input(" Press enter to finish ")
```

Comment: What are you entering as your input ?

Comment: its already in decimal as realnum .... (denary is just a less common term for base10 ... which `realnum` already is ...

Comment: This has to be a n-fold duplicate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python int to binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary)

Answer (score 2):

```
print("In Binary that is", bin(realnum)[2:])
print("In Denary that is", realnum)
```

is all you want I think ... based on how I interpreted your question

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to convert input into binary.  If so, you can use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> # Get the input as an integer
>>> realnum = int(input())
123
>>> # Make it binary
>>> format(realnum, '08b')
'01111011'
>>> x = format(realnum, '08b')
>>> # Put it back as an integer
>>> int(x, 2)
123
>>>
```

So, your code becomes:

```
print(" Enter a number")
realnum = int(input())
print("In Binary that is", format(realnum, '08b'))
print("In Denary that is", realnum)
input(" Press enter to finish ")
```

Comment: does bin not work in python3+? afaik he can already print it as binary ... tbh I think this question should be closed for the "must have a minimal understanding of the problem"

Comment: @JoranBeasley - No, it does.  I just think `format` is cleaner.  Just a style thing though. :)

Comment: but that doesnt have anything to do with his question is all :/ still I do agree

Comment: @JoranBeasley - Truth is, I have no clue what the OP's exact problem is.  He was very vague.  I'm just giving him something that I think will help him.  It's as good as I can do with what he gave.

Comment: yeah I gave you +1 I think he is really just asking how to print realnum in base10 (which leads me to think this should be closed for lack of minimal understanding)

Comment: @JoranBeasley - Well thank you.  Let me return the favor.  And I also voted to close this.  No offense at all to the OP but this question really violates the SO guidelines for questions.