# Need assistance in tracking down conversion error

Tags: python, binary, project

I know this might be a bit confusing but I'm new to Python. I have the task of a school project to create a binary to denary converter that takes denary up to 255 and up to 8-bit binary.

I basically take the input, split it, check it, put it into a list, work it out, put it into another list and print the done list. It all works apart from the last part - the conversion. Thanks in advance.

I get this error on both conversions:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\massi_000\Desktop\COM\Task 1 #2.5.py", line 101, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\massi_000\Desktop\COM\Task 1 #2.5.py", line 91, in main
    checkUp(noToConvert, mainOp)
  File "C:\Users\massi_000\Desktop\COM\Task 1 #2.5.py", line 80, in checkUp
    binaryToDenary(noToConvert)
  File "C:\Users\massi_000\Desktop\COM\Task 1 #2.5.py", line 30, in binaryToDenary
    while int(doneListBin[int(r)]) > 1:
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my full code.

```
doneListBin = []
doneListDen = []
splitList = []
doneList = []


def denaryToBinary(splitList):
    #Works binary
    for r in splitList:
        doneListDen.append(int(splitList[int(r)]) % 2)
        while int(doneListDen[int(r)]) > 1:
            doneListDen.append(int(splitList[int(r)]) % 2)
    print(doneListDen)

def binaryToDenary(splitList):
    #Works denary
    for r in splitList:
        doneListBin.append(int(splitList[int(r)]) * 2 ** (int(r) + 1))
        while int(doneListBin[int(r)]) > 1:
            doneListBin.append(int(doneListBin[int(r)]) * 2 ** (int(r) + 1))
    print(doneListBin)
```

ALL FINE PAST HERE

```
def checkUp(noToConvert, mainOp):
    try:
        if int(noToConvert) < 0:
            raise ValueError

        elif noToConvert.isdigit() == False:
            raise ValueError

        elif mainOp == 'd':
            if int(noToConvert) > 255:
                raise ValueError

            else:
                #Splits input for checking & passes
                splitList.extend(noToConvert)
                print(splitList)
                denaryToBinary(noToConvert)


        elif mainOp == 'b':


            #Makes sure it's not huge
            if int(len(str(noToConvert))) > 8:
                raise ValueError

            #Splits input for checking
            splitList.extend(noToConvert)
            print(splitList)

            #Makes it 8-bit
            if int(len(noToConvert)) < 8:
                for i in range(8 - int(len(noToConvert))):
                    splitList.insert(0, 0)
            #while int(len(str(splitList))) < 8:
             #   splitList.insert(0, 0)
               # print(splitList)


            #Should only accept valid inputs (0s and 1s)
            for i in splitList:
                if int(splitList[int(i)]) == 0 or int(splitList[int(i)]) == 1:
                    print(str(i) + ' in range')

                else:
                    raise ValueError
            binaryToDenary(noToConvert)
    except ValueError:
        main()


def main():
    ###     CHOICES     ###
    mainOp = input("Do you want to convert from (D)enary or from (B)inary?: ").lower()
    noToConvert = input("What is the number to convert?: ")

    if mainOp in ("d", "denary", "b", "binary"):
        checkUp(noToConvert, mainOp)


    else:
        raise ValueError



        #   EXECUTION    #
main()
```

Comment: You have at least two statements that could have caused that exception, and without posting a traceback there's no good way anyone can guess which one is at fault. This is one of many reasons you should always post the full traceback, not just a description of the error.

Comment: Why did you post functions that are commented out? If they aren't relevant to the sample, don't post them.

Comment: or you can just look for your classmates work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798195/how-would-i-turn-a-number-into-its-binary-representation/19798354#19798354

Comment: Meanwhile, without having a complete example—including code, input, and expected and actual output—it's going to be very hard for anyone to figure out what you've done wrong. And having a whole bunch of irrelevant code makes it harder as well. Please give us a [Minimal, complete, valid example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Also, i'm not allowed to use bin() or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
def binaryToDenary(splitList):
    doneListBin = []
    for r in range(0, len(splitList)):
        doneDigit = int(splitList[int(r)]) * 2 ** (len(splitList)-int(r)-1)
        doneListBin.append(doneDigit)
    print sum(doneListBin)
```

also in checkUp(noToConvert, mainOp), you should use binaryToDenary(splitList)  instead of binaryToDenary(noToConvert)

For denary to binary

```
def denaryToBinary(noStr):
    #Works binary
    doneListDen = []
    noToConvert = int(noStr)
    while(noToConvert>0):
       doneListDen.append(noToConvert%2)
       noToConvert = noToConvert // 2
    doneListDen.reverse()
    print doneListDen
```

Comment: Thanks! - 1 problem: This works great from bin to den, but from den to bin it prints a bunch of jibberish:                                                                                                                              Like about 100 lines of:                                                                   -322, 8e-323, 4e-323, 2e-323, 1e-323, 5e-324

Comment: I made a mistake. Try the new den to bin function.

Comment: Still does the same unfortunately. The reverse() seems to have done nothing. Thank you for helping, any ideas?

Comment: def denaryToBinary(splitList):
   #Works binary
    noToConvert = int(splitList)
    while noToConvert > 0:
       doneListDen.append(noToConvert%2)
       noToConvert = noToConvert / 2
    doneListDen.reverse()
    print("your answer is: " + str(doneListDen))
    time.sleep(5)

Comment: Do you want to convert from (D)enary or from (B)inary?: d
What is the number to convert?: 45
['4', '5']
your answer is: [5e-324, 1e-323, 1.5e-323, 3e-323, 5.4e-323, 1.1e-322, 2.2e-322, 4.45e-322, 8.9e-322, 1.78e-321, 3.557e-321, 7.115e-321, 1.423e-320, 2.846e-320, 5.6916e-320, 1.13833e-319, 2.27665e-319, 4.5533e-319, 9.1066e-319, 1.821324e-318, 3.642647e-318, 7.285294e-318, 1.457059e-317, 2.914118e-317, 5.8282355e-317, 1.1656471e-316, 2.3312942e-316, 4.6625884e-316, 9.3251768e-316, 1.865035363e-315, 3.730070726e-315, 7.460141453e-315, 1.4920282905e-                        ETC.

Comment: @user3207904 I got it. You are using python 3. And dividing two integers in python 3 doesn't behave the same as in python 2. You can replace / with // to yield integer results. I edited my code above.