# Printing Binary in Python

Tags: python

I need to print the numbers 0-250 in binary efficiently

So far I have tried the code: 
         "{0:bn}".function(

Does anyone have an idea how I would use this code or any suggestions of different that i can use to print the numbers 0-250 in binary.

Comment: A simple Google search would have answered the question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python int to binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in python `bin` function can do that:

```
>>> bin(2)
'0b10'         # value produced by bin is prefixed with 0b, it indicates valid python binary format
>>> bin(4)
'0b100'
>>> bin(100)
'0b1100100'
```

you can also use format:

```
>>> "{:b}".format(10)
'1010'
```

try like this: using `bin`

```
[bin(x) for x in range(251)]     # produces list of binary from 0-250
```

using format:

```
["{:b}".format(x) for x in range(251)]
```

you can print like this:

```
for x in range(251):
    print(bin(x))
```

or:

```
for x in range(251):
    print("{:b}".fromat(x))
```

Comment: @Zinc check the code carefully, you will get it

Comment: That solution dosnt seem to work for me

Comment: @Zinc what you trying to achieve??. what exactly you tried??

Comment: Im trying to make a program that when you run it, it prints the numbers from 0-250 on the screen in binary but coding it in an efficient way so basically not coding an individual print for each number.

Comment: what you have typed, can you show me???, check my last two code

Comment: i can get the bin one to work but the code that uses the format function im having problems with.

Comment: ahh i see the problem, i have it working now. thanks for your help i appreciate it