# Special counting

Tags: python, binary, counting

I want to fill an array in python with ones in a specific way. An example with 4 digits is the easiest way to explain:

```
0000, 0001, 0010, 0100, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111
```

I need a list with 8 digits, so just writing them down is not an option. I really have no idea how to do that..

Edit: To clarify the problem. I need for the first entry all digits to be 0. Then all possibilities with just one 1, then all possibilities with two 1's and so forth. The last entry would be all 1.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do a lot more critical thinking about the problem! This is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as written.

Comment: Please note that 0010 is an octal literal and thus `8 == 0010`

Comment: @robyschek I assume he's looking for `["00000000", "00000001", "00000010", ...]`

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary

Comment: @cricket_007 that doesn't really help, though, since he's not counting in binary (`0001`, `0010`, `0100` instead of `0001`, `0010`, `0011`)

Comment: @Adam: You are completely correct. Binary counting would be no problem for me..

Comment: I've written an answer, but now I see the example given is peculiar: it only has 11 numbers in it. What happened to 0011, 0101, 0110, 0111 and 1011?

Comment: @PaulHankin If you stop thinking in binary and just look at patterns, this becomes clearer! It's not binary *REALLY*. `0010` is not 2, it's just `ooxo`. There is no `ooxx` element in that pattern.

Comment: At least I think so.... The edit just now has muddied those waters. It would be great if someone could close this until we had some code to look at or at least a clear problem statement, but we need another voter.

Comment: @Paul: Oh you are correct Paul. That was a mistake by myself. I need all numbers. To sort the list solved my problem in principle. But I need to print an array entry: w[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0] , w[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][1], ... and so forth. Know I don't know how to put the numbers into the array :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way is to sort all the binary representations by the number of 1s they have. Since python sort is stable, this also keeps the original order between numbers with the same number of 1s.

```
sorted(('{:08b}'.format(i) for i in xrange(256)), key=lambda x: x.count('1'))
```

Comment: wow. That's...original.

Answer (score 0):

Its not in the same order in your example, I assume you don't need the specific order:

```
for i in range(256):
    print "{:08b}".format(i)
```

Also I assume you need values in strings, since you specified stuff like 000001 and that expression is meaningless in numbers (equals 1).

Comment: I'm quite sure that order is relevant, but yes this would otherwise work. Note that the word "Counting" is used several times, which is ordered by definition

Comment: Sorry, but your answer doesn't work.

Comment: is it because the ordering matters? or another reason?

Comment: The first entry would be all zeroes, then all possibilities with only one 1, then all possibilities with two 1's, and so forth.

Comment: The last entry would be then all 1

Comment: so yes, its the ordering. just use sorted() on the result list, as the other answer explained.