# Python: Find longest binary gap in binary representation of an integer number

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I would like to know if my implementation is efficient.
I have tried to find the simplest and low complex solution to that problem using python.

```
def count_gap(x):
    """
        Perform Find the longest sequence of zeros between ones "gap" in binary representation of an integer

        Parameters
        ----------
        x : int
            input integer value

        Returns
        ----------
        max_gap : int
            the maximum gap length

    """
    try:
        # Convert int to binary
        b = "{0:b}".format(x)
        # Iterate from right to lift 
        # Start detecting gaps after fist "one"
        for i,j in enumerate(b[::-1]):
            if int(j) == 1:
                max_gap = max([len(i) for i in b[::-1][i:].split('1') if i])
                break
    except ValueError:
        print("Oops! no gap found")
        max_gap = 0
    return max_gap
```

let me know your opinion.

Comment: The [codility BinaryGap test](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/1-iterations/binary_gap/) allows for solutions written in 18 different languages: `C, C++, C#, Go, Java 8, Java 11, JavaScript, Kotlin, Lua, Objective-C, Pascal, PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, Scala, Swift 4, Visual Basic`. So I don't see any reason to restrict this question to Python only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your implementation converts the integer to a base two string then visits each character in the string.  Instead, you could just visit each bit in the integer using `<<` and `&`.  Doing so will avoid visiting each bit twice (first to convert it to a string, then to check if if it's a "1" or not in the resulting string).  It will also avoid allocating memory for the string and then for each substring you inspect.

You can inspect each bit of the integer by visiting 1 << 0, 1 << 1, ..., 1 << (x.bit_length).

For example:

```
def max_gap(x):
    max_gap_length = 0
    current_gap_length = 0
    for i in range(x.bit_length()):
        if x & (1 << i):
            # Set, any gap is over.
            if current_gap_length > max_gap_length:
                max_gap_length = current_gap_length
            current_gap_length = 0
         else:
            # Not set, the gap widens.
            current_gap_length += 1
    # Gap might end at the end.
    if current_gap_length > max_gap_length:
        max_gap_length = current_gap_length
    return max_gap_length
```

Comment: I'd suggest using the `int.bit_length` method instead of the `ceil(log2(...))` computation, to avoid corner-case errors due to rounding.

Comment: You have said Your implementation converts the integer to a base two string then visits each character in the string but that is not completely correct as I break after detecting one then I split. Could you plz highlight why your implementation should be better in terms of time and memory complexity, please.

Comment: You still have to visit each character.  How else can `split` find the right place to split?  It visits each character until it finds the value you supplied.

Comment: Hi  Jean, Your code is much slower than the one I provided. I will add the time complexity in the answer (as running time test code).

Comment: Note that "complexity" is not the same as "wallclock runtime".

Comment: Complexity wise, I think I've convinced myself that your solution is O(N) (so is mine) and I doubt it's possible to do better than that.  So all that's left is constant factors and in Python those are often minimized by making sure you use built-in functionality (since the C implementation is typically much faster than anything you can do with Python code).  On PyPy the story may be different.

Comment: Thanks, Jean. In the beginning, i was afraid to publish my codes in StackOverflow (negative comments), but you really encouraged me to keep on going (publish and optimize).  Good luck

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: It looks to me like your algorithm is actually O((log x)^2) where the OP's is O(log x), which leads to dramatic differences in runtime as the OP's test case has log(x) around half a million.  The problem appears to be the calculation of `1 << i`, which requires zeroing i/8 bytes of memory and consequently runs in O(i) time.  The `.format` OP uses, on the other hand, presumably just loops through the bytes of x, converts each to an 8-byte string, and writes the result of the conversion into a buffer, which is an O(log x) operation that's done once.

Comment: Nice catch.  I thought about taking the `1 << i` out and replacing it with a loop variable and `loop_var << 1`.  Even with this change, my version is still _slower_ than the OPs (except for very very small integers).  Often, complexity doesn't matter in Python (even if you can figure out - what about the `range`, what about the `b[::-1]`, etc) because finding some way to push a "more" complex operation off into C (`format`) still beats a "less" complex operation in byte code.  My version goes through a whole byte code interpretation loop for each bit!  Seriously big `k` being applied there.

Answer (score 65):

I do realize that brevity does not mean readability nor efficiency.

However, ability to spell out solution in spoken language and implement it in Python in no time constitutes efficient use of my time.

For binary gap: hey, lets convert int into binary, strip trailing zeros, split at '1' to list, then find longest element in list and get this element lenght.

```
def binary_gap(N):
    return len(max(format(N, 'b').strip('0').split('1')))
```

Comment: Super nice :thumbsup:

Comment: This one liner really very efficient. But I got stuck in one point, what is the functionality of strip? I ran that code without using strip and it had same output. Thank you in advance.

Comment: By definition binary gap is 'zeros between ones', therefore one should not consider trailing zeros as binary gap. Try to run both versions with int 32 (100000 in binary). With strip you get 0 (there is no binary gap) without strip you get 5 (which is incorrect as there is no 5 zeros between ones).

Comment: If you are looking for performance: bin(), which @Orenico uses in his answers, is quite a bit faster than format(N, 'b').

Comment: @quassy - please define 'quite a bit faster'. Casual check with timeit & Python 3.8 shows that format() is little bit faster than bin()[2:].  Same casual check also indicates that one can claim `f"{N:b}"` to be "quite a bit faster".

Comment: Testing my implementation I see small but probably not significant differences for testing all numbers from 1 to 21474836 (.format() took 26.1s; format() took 25.6s; bin() took 24.2s; also for bigger ranges). This seems to confirm [other observations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary-string#comment29223504_699892).

Comment: If you want to run [the corresponding Codility test](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/1-iterations/binary_gap/start/), then just rename `binary_gap` as `solution`. This solution scores as [100% correct](https://i.imgur.com/blMWx8I.png) and it passes [15 of 15 tests](https://i.imgur.com/4BPWiea.png).

Answer (score 7):

```
def max_gap(N):
    xs = bin(N)[2:].strip('0').split('1')
    return max([len(x) for x in xs])
```

Explanation:

1. Both leading and trailing zeros are redundant with binary gap finding
   as they are not bounded by two 1's (left and right respectively)
2. So step 1 striping zeros left and right
3. Then splitting by 1's yields all sequences of 0'z
4. Solution: The maximum length of 0's sub-strings

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is efficient in grouping elements of an iterable like a string. You could approach it like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

def count_gap(x):
    b = "{0:b}".format(x)
    return max(len(list(v)) for k, v in groupby(b.strip("0")) if k == "0")

number = 123456
print(count_gap(number))
```

First we strip all zeroes from the ends, because a gap has to have on both ends a one. Then `itertools.groupby` groups ones and zeros and we extract the key (i.e. "0" or "1") together with a group (i.e. if we convert it into a list, it looks like "0000" or "11"). Next we collect the length for every group v, if k is zero. And from this we determine the largest number, i.e. the longest gap of zeroes amidst the ones.

Answer (score 2):

I think the accepted answer dose not work when the input number is 32 (100000). Here is my solution:

```
def solution(N):
    res = 0
    st = -1
    for i in range(N.bit_length()):
        if N & (1 << i):
            if st != -1:
                res = max(res, i - st - 1)
            st = i

    return res
```

Comment: This is the part of review answer in stackoverflow. Add some explanation though code is explanatory.

Comment: Add explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
def solution(N):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    count = 0
    gap_list=[]
    bin_var = format(N,"b")
    for bit in bin_var:
        if (bit =="1"):
            gap_list.append(count)
            count =0
        else:
            count +=1
    return max(gap_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```py
def solution(N):
    num = binary = format(N, "06b")
    char = str(num)
    find=False
    result, conteur=0, 0

    for c in char:
        if c=='1' and not find:
            find = True
            
        if find and c=='0':
            conteur+=1

        if c=='1':
            if result<conteur:
                result=conteur
            conteur=0

    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

this also works:

```
def binary_gap(n):
    max_gap = 0
    current_gap = 0

    # Skip the tailing zero(s)
    while n > 0 and n % 2 == 0:
        n //= 2

    while n > 0:
        remainder = n % 2
        if remainder == 0:
            # Inside a gap
            current_gap += 1
        else:
            # Gap ends
            if current_gap != 0:
                max_gap = max(current_gap, max_gap)
                current_gap = 0
        n //= 2

    return max_gap
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I would solve it using generators.

```
from itertools import dropwhile

# a generator that returns binary 
# representation of the input
def getBinary(N):
    while N:
        yield N%2
        N //= 2

def longestGap(N):
    longestGap = 0
    currentGap = 0

    # we want to discard the initial 0's in the binary
    # representation of the input
    for i in dropwhile(lambda x: not x, getBinary(N)):
        if i:
            # a new gap is found. Compare to the maximum
            longestGap = max(currentGap, longestGap)
            currentGap = 0
        else:
            # extend the previous gap or start a new one
            currentGap+=1

    return longestGap
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done using strip() and split() function :
Steps:

1. Convert to binary (Remove first two characters )
2. Convert int to string
3. Remove the trailing and starting 0 and 1 respectively
4. Split with 1 from the string to find the subsequences of strings
5. Find the length of the longest  substring

Second `strip('1')` is not mandatory but it will decrease the cases to be checked and will improve the time complexity 
Worst case T

```
def solution(N):
    return len(max(bin(N)[2:].strip('0').strip('1').split('1')))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def solution(N: int) -> int:
    binary = bin(N)[2:]
    longest_gap = 0
    gap = 0
    for char in binary:
        if char == '0':
            gap += 1
        else:
            if gap > longest_gap:
                longest_gap = gap
            gap = 0
    return longest_gap
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer is better than the others. This will help people learn from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def solution(N):
# write your code in Python 3.6

    iterable_N = "{0:b}".format(N)
    max_gap = 0
    gap_positions = []
    for index, item in enumerate(iterable_N):
        if item == "1":
            if len(gap_positions) > 0:
               if (index - gap_positions[-1]) > max_gap:
                    max_gap = index - gap_positions[-1]
            gap_positions.append(index)
    max_gap -= 1 
    return max_gap if max_gap >= 0 else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using bit shift operator (100%). Basically the complexity is O(N).

```
def solution(N):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    meet_one = False
    count = 0
    keep = []
    while N:
        if meet_one and N & 1 == 0:
            count+=1
        
        if  N & 1:
            meet_one = True
            keep.append(count)
            count = 0
        N >>=1

    return max(keep)
```

Answer (score 0):

this also works:

```
def solution(N):
    bin_num = str(bin(N)[2:])
    list1 = bin_num.split('1')
    max_gap =0
    if bin_num.endswith('0'):
        len1 = len(list1) - 1
    else:
        len1 = len(list1)
    if len1 != 0:
        for i in range(len1):
            if max_gap < len(list1[i]):
                max_gap = len(list1[i])
    return max_gap
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(number):

    bits = [int(digit) for digit in bin(number)[2:]]
    occurences = [i for i, bit in enumerate(bits) if(bit==1)]
    res = [occurences[counter+1]-a-1 for counter, a in enumerate(occurences) if(counter+1 < len(occurences))]

    if(not res):
        print("Gap: 0")
    else:
        print("Gap: ", max(res))

number = 1042
solution(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
def solution(number):
    # convert number to binary then strip trailing zeroes
    binary = ("{0:b}".format(number)).strip("0")
    longest_gap = 0
    current_gap = 0
    for c in binary:
        if c is "0":
           current_gap = current_gap + 1
        else:
           current_gap = 0

        if current_gap > longest_gap:
           longest_gap = current_gap 


    return longest_gap
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_gap(N):
    bin = '{0:b}'.format(N)
    binary_gap = []
    bin_list = [bin[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(bin), 1)] 

    for i in range(len(bin_list)):
        if (bin_list[i] == '1'):
            # print(i)
            # print(bin_list[i])
            # print(binary_gap)
            gap = []
            for j in range(len(bin_list[i+1:])):
                # print(j)
                # print(bin_list[j])
                if(bin_list[i+j+1]=='1'):
                    binary_gap.append(j)
                    # print(j)
                    # print(bin_list[j])
                    # print(binary_gap)
                    break
                elif(bin_list[i+j+1]=='0'):
                    # print(i+j+1)
                    # print(bin_list[j])
                    # print(binary_gap)
                    continue
                else:
                    # print(i+j+1)
                    # print(bin_list[i+j])
                    # print(binary_gap)
                    break
        else:
            # print(i)
            # print(bin_list[i])
            # print(binary_gap)
            binary_gap.append(0)


    return max(binary_gap)
    pass
```

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57247918/edit) your answer to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find(s, ch):
    return [i for i, ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == ch]

def solution(N):
    get_bin = lambda x: format(x, 'b')
    binary_num = get_bin(N)
    print(binary_num)
    binary_str = str(binary_num)
    list_1s = find(binary_str,'1')
    diffmax = 0
    for i in range(len(list_1s)-1):
        if len(list_1s)<1:
            diffmax = 0
            break
        else:
            diff = list_1s[i+1] - list_1s[i] - 1
            if diff > diffmax:
                diffmax = diff
    return diffmax
    pass
```

Comment: Can you explain your code? Dropping code without doing so might not be that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using iterators and generators that will handle edge cases such as the binary gap for the number 32 (100000) being 0 and the binary gap for 0 being 0. It doesn't create a list, instead relying on iterating and processing elements of the bit string one step at a time for a memory efficient solution.

```
def solution(N):
    def counter(n):
        count = 0
        preceeding_one = False
        for x in reversed(bin(n).lstrip('0b')):
            x = int(x)
            if x == 1:
                count = 0
                preceeding_one = True
                yield count
            if preceeding_one and x == 0:
                count += 1
                yield count
        yield count
    return(max(counter(N)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more that seems to be easy to understand.

```
def count_gap(x):
     binary_str = list(bin(x)[2:].strip('0'))
     max_gap = 0 
     n = len(binary_str)
     pivot_point = 0

     for i in range(pivot_point, n):
         zeros = 0
         for j in range(i + 1, n):
              if binary_str[j] == '0':
                   zeros += 1 
              else:
                   pivot_point = j
                   break

         max_gap = max(max_gap, zeros)

     return max_gap
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really old, I know. But here's mine:

```
def solution(N):
    gap_list = [len(gap) for gap in bin(N)[2:].strip("0").split("1") if gap != ""]
    
    return max(gap_list) if gap_list else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another efficient solution. Hope it may helps you. You just need to pass any number in function and it will return longest Binary gap.

```
def LongestBinaryGap(num):

n = int(num/2)
bin_arr = []

for i in range(0,n):
    if i == 0:
        n1 = int(num/2)
        bin_arr.append(num%2)
    else:
        bin_arr.append(n1%2)
        n1 = int(n1/2)

        if n1 == 0:
            break

print(bin_arr)
result = ""
count = 0
count_arr = []

for i in bin_arr:
    if result == "found":
        if i == 0:
            count += 1
        else:
            if count > 0:
                count_arr.append(count)
                count = 0
    if i == 1:
        result = 'found'
    else:
        pass

if len(count_arr) == 0:
    return 0
else:
    return max(count_arr)

print(LongestBinaryGap(1130))  # Here you can pass any number.
```

Answer (score 0):

My code in python 3.6 scores 100
Get the binary Number .. Get the positions of  1
get the abs differennce between 1.. sort it

```
 S = bin(num).replace("0b", "")
          res = [int(x) for x in str(S)]
          print(res)
          if res.count(1) < 2 or res.count(0) < 1:
              print("its has no binary gap")
          else: 
            positionof1 = [i for i,x in enumerate(res) if x==1]
            print(positionof1)
            differnce = [abs(j-i) for i,j in zip(positionof1, positionof1[1:])]
            differnce[:] = [differnce - 1 for differnce in differnce]
            differnce.sort()
            print(differnce[-1])
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def solution(N):
    return len(max(bin(N).strip('0').split('1')[1:]))
```

Comment: Does this offer any benefit over other solutions offered here? Please [edit] to explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(N):
    maksimum = 0 
    zeros_list = str(N).split('1')
    if zeros_list[-1] != "" :
        zeros_list.pop()
        
    for item in zeros_list :
        if  len(item) > maksimum :
            maksimum = len(item)
    return(maksimum)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def solution(N):
    bin_num = str(bin(N)[2:])
    bin_num = bin_num.rstrip('0')
    bin_num = bin_num.lstrip('0')
    list1 = bin_num.split('1')
    max_gap = 0

    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if len(list1[i]) > max_gap:
            max_gap = len(list1[i])

    return (max_gap)
```

Comment: This works fine with any "Binary Gap " Lesson 1 codility

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Your code does not even run, because of the missing indention. Please fix that!

Comment: @hellow, I had problems while posting . The code works absolutely fine .

Comment: @Nic3500 I acknowledge, this is my first time :)

Comment: Then please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . There is a ton of help available how to format your answer properly, so please don't use that as an excuse ;) (I don't drive a car, before I took some driving lessons. That's (nearly) the same. Read the instructions first and post afterwards)

Answer (score -1):

```
def solution(N):
    # Convert the number to bin 
    br = bin(N).split('b')[1]
    sunya=[]
    groupvalues=[]
    for i in br:
        count = i
        if int(count) == 1:
            groupvalues.append(len(sunya))
            sunya=[]
        if int(count) == 0:
            sunya.append('count') 

    return max(groupvalues)
```