# How to deal with bit manipulation with longest binary gap?

Tags: python

I read a little bit and found [python-longest-binary-gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951591/python-find-longest-binary-gap-in-binary-representation-of-an-integer-number) SO question

```
def solution(N):
    max_gap = 0
    new_gap = 0
    for i in range(N.bit_length()):
        if N & (1 << i):
            if new_gap > max_gap:
                max_gap = new_gap
            new_gap =0
        else:
            new_gap += 1
    if new_gap > max_gap:
        max_gap = new_gap
    return max_gap
```

The problem is that it gives the wrong solution for 32
(5 instead of 0) or 64.
How to fix this?

Comment: Use PyCharm as your IDE and learn to use the debugger. Step through your code, line by line, examining the value of variables, and the answer will be obvious. You don't need us for questions like this - just your debugger :-)

Comment: Some of the answers in the question you link to address this problem

Comment: It is because you start counting from the first bit even if it's zero. You need to start counting only when encountering a 1. I am really amazed this gets so upvoted, just a piece of code with "why this not working" AND with a link to the answer...

Comment: @RichardRublev yes, the community version is excellent, ***and*** it is free even for commercial use. I have used that paid/pro version, but even most companies I work for only use the community edition, and it is more than good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pandas solution to this problem:

```
import pandas as pd

def getlargestgap(x):
  df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(list, bin(x)[2:])), columns=['A'])
  df['B'] = df.groupby(df.A.ne(df.A.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()+1 
  df['Truth'] = df['A'] == '0'
  return df.loc[df['Truth'] == True]['B'].max() 

getlargestgap(23432124)

# 4
```

Comment: What does bin stand for?

Comment: it converts the number to binary string

Answer (score 1):

I marked `new_gap=-1` until we encounter an actual bit-1.

```
def solution(N):
    max_gap = 0
    new_gap = -1
    for i in range(N.bit_length()):
        if N & (1 << i):
            if new_gap > max_gap:
                max_gap = new_gap
            new_gap = 0
        elif new_gap >= 0:
            new_gap += 1
    if new_gap > max_gap:
        max_gap = new_gap
    return max_gap 

# test
for i in range(1,33):
    print(i, solution2(i))
```

Output:

```
1 0
2 1
3 0
4 2
5 1
6 1
7 0
8 3
9 2
10 1
11 1
12 2
13 1
14 1
15 0
16 4
17 3
18 2
19 2
20 2
21 1
22 1
23 1
24 3
25 2
26 1
27 1
28 2
29 1
30 1
31 0
32 5
```