# Converting hex to binary in array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on Visual Studio about python Project and The user   input like that `010203` and 
I use this code for saparating the input:

```
dynamic_array = [ ] 
hexdec = input("Enter the hex number to binary ");
strArray = [hexdec[idx:idx+2]  for idx in range(len(hexdec)) if idx%2 == 0]
dynamic_array = strArray
print(dynamic_array[0] + " IAM" )  
print(dynamic_array[1] + " NOA" )
print(dynamic_array[2] + " FCI" )
```

So, the output is:

```
01 IAM
02 NOA
03 FCI
```

However my expected output converting this hex numbers to binary numbers look like this:

```
00000001 IAM
00000010 NOA
00000011 FCI
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `'{0:b}'.format(int(hex_val, 16)).zfill(8)`. It's a lot easier if you think of hex as a plain number. From there, you just search your way to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python int to binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a lot easier if you thnk of hex as a integer (number).
There's a lot of tips on how to convert integers to different outcomes, but one useful string representation tool is `.format()` which can format a integer (and others) to various outputs.

This is a combination of:

- [Convert hex string to int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)
- [Python int to binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary)

The solutions would be:

```
binary = '{:08b}'.format(int(hex_val, 16))
```

And the end result code would look something like this:

```
def toBin(hex_val):
    return '{:08b}'.format(int(hex_val, 16)).zfill(8)

hexdec = input("Enter the hex number to binary ");
dynamic_array = [toBin(hexdec[idx:idx+2]) for idx in range(len(hexdec)) if idx%2 == 0]
print(dynamic_array[0] + " IAM" )  
print(dynamic_array[1] + " NOA" )
print(dynamic_array[2] + " FCI" )
```

Rohit also proposed a pretty good solution, but I'd suggest you swap the contents of `toBin()` with `bin(int())` rather than doing it per print statement.

I also restructured the code a bit, because I saw no point in initializing `dynamic_array` with a empty list. Python doesn't need you to set up variables before assigning values to them. There was also no point in creating `strArray` just to replace the empty `dynamic_array` with it, so concatenated three lines into one.

machnic also points out a good programming tip, the use of `format()` on your entire string. Makes for a very readable code :)

Hope this helps and that my tips makes sense.

Comment: Thank you @Torxed you safe my life

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic_array = [ ] 
hexdec = input("Enter the hex number to binary ");
strArray = [hexdec[idx:idx+2]  for idx in range(len(hexdec)) if idx%2 == 0]
dynamic_array = strArray
print((bin(int(dynamic_array[0],16))[2:]).zfill(8)+ " IAM" )  
print((bin(int(dynamic_array[1],16))[2:]).zfill(8) + " NOA" )
print((bin(int(dynamic_array[2],16))[2:]).zfill(8) + " FCI")
```

Comment: Welcome and Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can `format` the string to achieve it. Your code may look like:

```
dynamic_array = [ ] 
hexdec = input("Enter the hex number to binary ")

strArray = [hexdec[idx:idx+2] for idx in range(len(hexdec)) if idx%2 == 0]
dynamic_array = strArray
print("{:08b} IAM".format(int(dynamic_array[0])))
print("{:08b} NOA".format(int(dynamic_array[1])))
print("{:08b} FCI".format(int(dynamic_array[2])))
```