# How to print binary numbers using f"" string instead of .format()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, f-string

For printing some numbers to their binary formats, we simply use the `.format()` method, like so:

```py
# Binary
for i in range(5+1):
    print("{0:>2} in binary is {0:>08b}".format(i))
```

Output:

```
0 in binary is 00000000
1 in binary is 00000001
2 in binary is 00000010
3 in binary is 00000011
4 in binary is 00000100
5 in binary is 00000101
```

Similar is for printing in other formats (hex and octal) which just requires replacing the latter braces to the digits we want to print. But is there a way to use the new `f""` string to replace the `.format()` command? I know this might seem trivial but I stumped over this while playing around with the new feature, besides `f""` makes the code shorter and more readable.

```py
for i in range(5+1):
    print(f'{0:>2} in binary is {0:>08b}')
# This prints out just 0s
```

Comment: Shouldn't you change `0` to `i` here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your f-string should have expressions in it rather than indices:

```
f'{i:>2} in binary is {i:>08b}'
```

Anywhere you had `0` in the original format string should be replaced by the actual first argument: in this case `i`.

**Caveat**

The expression in the f-string is evaluated twice, but the argument to `format` is only evaluated once when you access it by index. This matters for more complicated expressions. For example:

```
"{0:>2} in binary is {0:>08b}".format(i + 10)
```

Here the addition `i + 10` only happens once. On the other hand

```
f"{i+10:>2} in binary is {i+10:>08b}"
```

does the addition twice because it is equivalent to

```
"{:>2} in binary is {:>08b}".format(i + 10, i + 10)
```

Or

```
"{0:>2} in binary is {1:>08b}".format(i + 10, i + 10)
```

The workaround is to pre-compute the results of expressions that appear in your f-string more than once:

```
j = i + 10
f"{j:>2} in binary is {j:>08b}"
```

Now `j` is evaluated multiple times, but it's just a simple reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take:

In the old `.format()` the 0 represented the 1st element passed to the format function. `"{0:>2} in binary is {0:>08b}".format(i)`. 0 was used twice to access the first variable twice. Another way of writing it would be: `"{:>2} in binary is {:>08b}".format(i,i)` omitting the indices.

In the new `f''` format we pass variables/expressions instead.