# Coverting hex to bin and putting in another array Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I'm working on a Python 3 project. My code is more longer but I prepared for you a sample basic idea of my code which works.

```
arr = []
arr2 = []
number = (["01", "02", "03" ])
arr = number
print(arr) # Output : ["01", "02", "03"]
```

**Question:** 
How to convert this numbers into another array with converting hex to bin?
*Note:* 
My expected output is for arr2 : `["00000001", "00000010", "00000011"]`
And when I `print(arr2[0])` I want to see `00000001`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python int to binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the string formatter in a list comprehension:

```
['{:08b}'.format(int(n, 16)) for n in number]
```

This returns:

```
['00000001', '00000010', '00000011']
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This is I want to see, you make me happy :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the bin function. Convert an int to binary. the [2:] "cuts" the b0 (the function returns etc 03 -> b011) if you want to fill the number with 8 zeros use the zfill(8) function

```
number = (["01", "02", "03" ])
    arr = []
    for i in number:
        i = int(i)
        i = str(bin(i)[2:]).zfill(8)
        print(i)
        arr.append(str(i))


    print(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer

Answer (score 0):

as a one of possible ways:

```
hex_var = "02"
length = 8

a = bin(int(hex_var, 16))[2:]
print(str(a).zfill(length))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer