# Python format unsigned binary integer to IP address

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

How can I use python .format() to take an unsigned binary integer and output an ip address/netmask? For example,

```
print("Netmask {...} ".format('10001000100010001000100010001000'))
10001000.10001000.10001000.10001000
```

Comment: `socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('!L', int('10001000100010001000100010001000', 2)))`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Interesting, but I don't want to import Socket module just for this.

Comment: Is `'{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(s[:8], s[8:18], s[16:24], s[24:])` what you want?

Comment: @Goyo Yes! How could I be so blind?!

Comment: @Goyo If you make your comment an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2):

You can use your input, bitshift it after masking and put it back together:

```
number = int('10001000100010001000100010001000',2)

one = number & 0xff
two = (number & 0xff00) >> 8
three = (number & 0xff0000) >> 16
four = (number & 0xff000000) >> 24

print(f"{four}.{three}.{two}.{one}")
print(f"{four:b}.{three:b}.{two:b}.{one:b}")
```

Output

```
136.136.136.136                       # as normal int

10001000.10001000.10001000.10001000   # as binary int
```

---

You can use `"{:b}.{:b}.{:b}.{:b}".format(four,three,two,one)` instead of `f-strings` if you are below 3.6.

---

Disclaimer: this uses [Python int to binary string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary-string) applied to some binary bitshiftiness:

```
  10001000100010001000100010001000  # your number  
& 11111111000000000000000000000000  # 0xff000000
= 10001000000000000000000000000000  # then >> 24
                          10001000 

  10001000100010001000100010001000  # your number  
& 00000000111111110000000000000000  # 0xff0000
= 00000000100010000000000000000000  # then >> 16
                  0000000010001000  # etc.
```