# Can anybody explain me print statement in this code?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, gray-code

I found this code on internet but I am not able to understand how the print statement is working.

I have already tried to see many answers but none answers it perfectly.

```
def main():
    n=int(raw_input())
    for i in range(0, 1<<n):
        gray=i^(i>>1)
        print "{0:0{1}b}".format(gray,n),

main()
```

Comment: you mean string formatting ```"{0:0{1}b}".format(gray,n)```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for i in range(0, 1<<n):`
Here, `1 << n` shifts 1 by n bits to left. It means:
`if n = 1, 1 << 1 would be 10, 
   n = 2, 1 << 10 would be 100`  [2 = binary 10]
and so on.
For decimal number the answer is equivalent 2 to the power n.
For binary 'n' number of zeros are added.
So the range is `for i in range(0, 2 ** n)`.

```
gray=i^(i>>1)
```

Here `i>>1` shifts i by 1 bit to right. It means:

```
   if i = 1, 1 >> 1 would be 0,    
       i = 2, 10 >> 1 would be 1 [2 = binary 10]   
       i = 3, 100 >> 1 would be 10 (in binary) 2 in decimal
```

and so on.
For decimal numbers it is equivalent to dividing by 2 (and ignoring digits after . decimal point).
For binary last digit is erased.

`^` is exclusive OR operator. It is defined as:

```
0 ^ 0 = 0,     
0 ^ 1 = 1 ^ 0 = 1,   
1 ^ 1 = 0
```

```
print "{0:0{1}b}".format(gray,n)
```

Here {1} refers to n, b refers to binary. So gray is converted to binary and expressed in n digits.

Comment: You may see [Int to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary-string) or [Format specs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is known by the concept of ***Advanced string formatting***. Specifically, ***`PEP 3101 Advanced string Formatting`***

You may refer the [official documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#format-specifiers) for understanding purposes.