# Change an array of integers into binary array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have multiple arrays, each contain 6 integer values. eg `x[0. 1. 0. 2. 1. 2.]` i want to convert each value in each array into binary array e.g. `x_bin[0,0, 0,1, 0,0, 1,0, 0,1, 1,0]`. Note that initially my variable has 6  integer (from 0 - 2), i want my final result to contain 12 values (2 bits for each integer).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the values always 0, 1, or 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python int to binary string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary-string)

Comment: @hmm no not a duplicate, i already checked into what you have shared. It does not work for my case. I want to change the whole array at a time as I have multiple arrays.

Comment: @rassar yes, they are always, 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: It's a duplicate, with a bit of case-specific logic... `['{0:02b}'.format(x) for x in [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2]]` will change the entire array to two-bit binary strings. Another pass could split those strings and cast them to int...

Comment: @hmm thanks it is similar to what i am looking for but it will be more beneficial for my work if each character of the binary are separated into two different values eg. for ```2```  i want ```1,0``` instead of ```10```.

Comment: If you show your attempts to solve the problem, you may receive more specific help.

Answer (score 0):

Convert each number to binary, then convert each binary digit to an integer.

```
>>> x = [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2]
>>> [tuple(int(c) for c in '{:02b}'.format(i)) for i in x]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)]
```