# How to convert decimal number to binary without 0b using python?

Tags: python

I want to convert 2 as 10. but **bin()** function gives like `0b10`. How can I do it?

Comment: `bin(2)[2:]` should work?

Comment: you must remove that prefix with `bin(2)[2:]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python int to binary string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary-string)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the prefix with:

```
bin(2)[2:]
```