# Decimals to binary in Python

Tags: python, function, while-loop, binary

I'm trying to use a function (`dec2bin()`) to convert decimal numbers to binary. I see the input number being printed as binary but in the wrong order. What do I need to change? Or do I need to start over?

Here is the code with the function at first then the program:

```
def dec2bin(value):
  if value > 1:
    dec2bin(value//2)
    print (value%2, end = '')

invalue_ok = False
invalue = 0
```

```
while invalue_ok is False:
   invalue = int(input("Give a value: "))
   if invalue > 65535:
       print ("Wrong. Number too big. Try again.")
   elif invalue < 0:
       print ("Wrong. Can only handle positive numbers.")
   if invalue < 256:
       print ("Number", invalue, "fits in one byte and in binary is ", dec2bin(invalue))
   else:
        print ("Number", invalue, "fits in 16 bytes and in binary is", dec2bin(invalue))`
```

The output looks like this:
Give a value: 234
1101010Number 234 fits in one byte and in binary is  None

What can I do to get it right?

Comment: print returns None.

Comment: `if value > 1` misses last digit. That could explain things. you need `if value > 0`

Answer (score 0):

it works with

```py
if value>0:
```

it's in the good order

Answer (score 0):

There are three easier ways to do it:

The format method:

```
binary = "{0:b}".format(*number*)
```

The `bin` method (this also works with negative numbers):

```
binary = bin(*number*)
```

Or a function from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary-string):

```
def intToBin(n):
    if(n < 0):
        return -1
    elif(n == 0):
        return str(n)
    else:
        result = ""
        while(n != 0):
            result += str(n%2)
            n //= 2
        return result[::-1]

binary = intToBin(*number*)
```