# Print binary value Python

Tags: python

I already tried converting it to a string, adding `0` to it, but it still only shows me the decimal value, how can I make it show me its binary value?

If I try this:

```
binary = 0b010
print(binary)
```

or this:

```
binary = 0b010
print(str(binary))
```

which outputs this:

```
2
```

I also tried this:

```
binary = 0b010
print("{0:b}".format(binary))
```

which outputs this:

```
10
```

Desired output:

```
010
```

The bad part is that it does not fill in the number of 0 on the left, it gives me an output of `10` when I want `010`, but I want it to show the number of 0 possible for any binary that I put.

I'm new to Python, but every time I look for how to do it, it only appears to me as converting from integer to binary and showing it. But I can't use the `bin()` function, so I resorted to asking it here directly, thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python int to binary string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary-string)

Comment: @WArnold I Clarify that I cannot use the bin function

Comment: You can use format: ```print("0b{:b}".format(number))```.

Comment: It is basically, binary[2:]

Comment: @r_batra You cannot do that

Comment: @r_batra That of course doesn't work.

Comment: I suppose it would not be wrong to use format, the problem is that it is a method that receives integers too, just like bin

Comment: That is because `binary` is an int. There is no difference in typing `binary = 2` and `binary = 0b010`

Comment: I update my problem with format, could you please see it

Comment: Is there a reason you want a leading 0? In the binary representation "10", it doesn't really mean anything--it'd be like if someone asked how old you were, and you said "035 years old"

Answer (score 7):

You have a couple of ways of going about it.

The one that fits your use case the best is the `format()` method:

```
binary = 0b010

print("{:03b}".format(binary))
```

Which outputs:

```
010
```

Changing the 3 in `{:03b}` will change the minimum length of the output(it will add leading zeros if needed).

If you want to use it without leading zeros you can simply do `{:b}`.

Comment: 03b cannot be automatic, when I put a byte I don't want to change to 08b

Comment: It is impossible for it to be automatic because the variable itself doesn't know how many zeros you put when declaring it. Again `0b00000010`, `0b010` and `2` are exactly the same in the pythons eyes.

Answer (score 2):

You can try defining your own function to convert integers to binary:

```
def my_bin(x):
    bit = ''
    while x:
        bit += str(x % 2)
        x >>= 1
    return '0' + bit[::-1]

binary = 0b010
print(my_bin(binary))
```

Output:

```
010
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 & 3

```
number = 128

bin(number)
format(number, 'b')
"{0} in binary {0:b}".format(number)
```

Python 3

```
f"{number:b}"
```